# Convert Timecode to Frames with set start timecode

Tags: python-2.7, timecodes

I am using the below script to convert timecode to frames, which works but is only converting with a start timecode of 00:00:00:00. I want to be able to set the start timecode so the calculation is relative. Also it breaks if I se the frame rate to 23.976 or 29.97.

```
framerate = 24

def timecode_to_frames(timecode):
    return sum(f * int(t) for f,t in zip((3600*framerate, 60*framerate, framerate, 1), timecode.split(':')))

def frames_to_timecode(frames):
    return '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}:{3:02d}'.format(frames / (3600*framerate),
                                                    frames / (60*framerate) % 60,
                                                    frames / framerate % 60,
                                                    frames % framerate)

print timecode_to_frames('00:00:00:10')
print frames_to_timecode(10)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you convert your values to numeric first (eg. seconds), you can do arithmetic operations easily:

```
framerate = 23.976

def _seconds(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):  # value seems to be a timestamp
        _zip_ft = zip((3600, 60, 1, 1/framerate), value.split(':'))
        return sum(f * float(t) for f,t in _zip_ft)
    elif isinstance(value, (int, float)):  # frames
        return value / framerate
    else:
        return 0

def _timecode(seconds):
    return '{h:02d}:{m:02d}:{s:02d}:{f:02d}' \
            .format(h=int(seconds/3600),
                    m=int(seconds/60%60),
                    s=int(seconds%60),
                    f=round((seconds-int(seconds))*framerate))


def _frames(seconds):
    return seconds * framerate

def timecode_to_frames(timecode, start=None):
    return _frames(_seconds(timecode) - _seconds(start))

def frames_to_timecode(frames, start=None):
    return _timecode(_seconds(frames) + _seconds(start))


print(timecode_to_frames('00:00:18:10', start='00:00:05:15'))  # ~ 307
print(frames_to_timecode(307, start='00:00:05:15'))  # '00:00:18:10'
```

Comment: This works great, thanks. Is there anyway to deal with drop frame?

Comment: All explained here http://andrewduncan.net/timecodes, bit confusing though, sorry.

Comment: this is being done automatically, since we round the frame count to integers

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Finwood.

Comment: Hi Finwood, I spoke too soon, The above solution only works for 23.976, If i try with 24fps it does not work.

Comment: floating-point issues. I changed `int` to `round` inside `_timecode`, this should work better.

Comment: With this I get an error in line 17: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'

Comment: Sorry, version 2.7.11, windows

Comment: wrap `round...` with `int` to get `int(round(...))`

Comment: Took a bit of fiddling, but managed to get the result, thanks for your assistance Finwood.

Comment: this doesn't work. 
if you take, let's say '00:00:18:10' at 24fps, removing start parameters to simplify the maths, it return a duration of 432 frames but the real answer is 442. 432 correspond to '00:00:18:00' so 10 frames are missing

Comment: worked well got own framerate using cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

Comment: nice implementation, works like a charm!